# Manage a pie shop!

Tags: code-golf

## Summary

Code golf is good. [Pie is good](http://pieisgood.org). When you put the two together, only good stuff can happen.

## Specifications

In this challenge you will manage a pie shop. The user will be able to input five different commands: `list`, `count`, `buy`, `sell`, and `exit`. Here are the specifications for each:

- `list`

  - Print a list of all the pies owned, and how many. Separate with `|` and pad with a space on either side. `|`s must be aligned. Pie amount may be negative (that means you owe pie to someone `:(`). For example:

    ```
    | apple     | 500 |
    | blueberry | 2   |
    | cherry    | -30 |
    ```
- `count [type]`

  - Print how many `{{type}}` pies there are. Print "There is no `{{type}}` pie!" if there is none. `{{type}}` will always match the regex `\w+` (i.e, it will always be a single word). For example, if I had the amount of pies shown in the above example list, then

    ```
    > count apple
    500
    > count peach
    There is no peach pie!
    ```
- `buy [n] [type]`

  - Add `{{n}}` to the count of `{{type}}` pie, and print it. Create `{{type}}` pie if it does not exist. `{{n}}` will always match the regex `[0-9]+` (i.e, it will always be a number). Here's another example (with the same pie inventory as the previous examples):

    ```
    > count blueberry
    2
    > buy 8 blueberry
    10
    ```
- `sell [n] [type]`

  - Subtract `{{n}}` from the count of `{{type}}` pie, and print it. Create `{{type}}` pie if it does not exist. Pie can be negative (oh no, that would mean you owe someone pie!).

    ```
    > sell 15 blueberry
    -5
    > buy 5 blueberry
    0
    ```
- `exit`

  - Print "The pie store has closed!" and exit the program.

    ```
    > exit
    The pie store has closed!
    ```

## Further clarifications

- If a non-existing function is called (the first word), then print "That's not a valid command."
- If an existing function is called with invalid arguments (the words after the first word), how your program behaves doesn't matter. "Invalid arguments" includes too many arguments, too little arguments, `{{n}}` not being a number, etc.
- Pie is good.
- Your input must be distinguished from your output. If you are running the program on the command line/terminal/shell/other text-based thing, you must prefix input with "`> ​"` (a "greater than" sign and a space) or some other shell input prefix thing.
- Pie is good.
- If all of these clarifications are not good enough, here's some sample output:

  ```
  > list
  > buy 10 apple
  10
  > sell 10 blueberry
  -10
  > list
  | apple     | 10  |
  | blueberry | -10 |
  > count apple
  10
  > count peach
  There is no peach pie!
  > exit
  The pie store has closed!
  ```
- If you buy/sell pie and the net count becomes `0`, you can **either** keep it in the `list` or not, and you can **either** return `0` or `There is no {{type}} pie!` when you `count` it.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); shortest code wins.
- Did I mention that pie is good?

Comment: So just to clarify... is pie good?

Comment: Is it acceptable to keep a pie in the list with a count of zero? Like if you do `buy 1 apple` and `sell 1 apple`. And would it then be valid for `count apple` to return `0` instead of `There is no apple pie!`?

Comment: @IgbyLargeman Darn it, I thought I clarified everything! :P Added new test case to additional clarifications

Comment: @Doorknob hey! I'm outputting "there is no apple pie" after the last one has been sold.

Comment: @JanDvorak Alright, I suppose either way will work. Updated again

Comment: umm... I keep it in the `list` *and* I display "there is no apple pie"

Comment: @JanDvorak I keep getting the wording vague :P Edited once again

Comment: Could you please clarify if the numbers in the list have to be justified, and if extra spaces are allowed?

Comment: @WolframH It's up to you to interpret the rules however you want. Some people have added extra spaces, and that's okay; we code golfers are notorious for bending the rules :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Ruby, <del>335</del> 330

```
h=Hash.new 0
loop{$><<"> "
puts case gets when/^list/
h.map{|x|?|+" %%%ds |"%h.flatten.map{|e|e.to_s.size}.max*2%x}when/^count (.*)/
h[$1]!=0?h[$1]:"There is no #{$1} pie!"when/^buy#{m=" (.*)"*2}/
h[$2]+=$1.to_i when/^sell#{m}/
h[$2]-=$1.to_i when/^exit/
puts"The pie store has closed!"
break else"That's not a valid command."end}
```

Some tricks here:

```
?|+" %%%ds |"%[*h].flatten.map{|e|e.to_s.size}.max*2%x
```

Doorknob's idea to use a formatter is taken a step further here, literally. First, the longest string in the hash among all keys and values is formatted using `" %%%ds |"` to produce a string like `" %6s |"`. Yep, no shrinkwrapping each column separately. There was never the requirement to. One size fits all. Then this string is duplicated and used as a formatting string for the two-element array containing the current row. Finally, the `+` near the start gets its word and prepends a single leading pipe. Oh, and `puts` has a nice handling of arrays.

Ruby has interpolation in regex literals. It's a tight save, but it does save a little.

Ruby requires semicolons after the `when` expression, but not before the keyword. This leads to a weird rendering artifact when the semicolon is replaced with a newline.

And, of course, perlism known as magic globals and automatic matching of regex literals against them.

Also, most statements including `case` are expressions.

Comment: Very clever tricks! +1

Comment: Hmm, but why `Hash.new(0)` instead of `{}`?

Comment: @Doorknob Ruby's hashes can have default values (if you pass an object) or even generators (if you pass a block (key, hash -> value). If you don't pass either, the default value is `nil` (which doesn't allow addition). The literal uses `nil` as the default value.

Comment: Could save a few characters with `h=Hash.new(0)` => `h=Hash.new 0`, `print"> "` => `$><<'> '`, and I think `[*h]` can just be `h`.  I tried putting together a version without the switch statement since all that boilerplate text really adds up:  https://gist.github.com/chron/6315218.  I was trying to make something work with `ruby -ap` but the requirement for the prompt makes it hard :<

Comment: @chron thanks! Can't believe I missed the first one, and I'm not sure why I thought `$><<` printed a newline. As for the last suggestion... unfortunately, hashes don't have a "flatten" method.

Comment: @JanDvorak I guess it depends on your version, it works for me.  Maybe only 1.9.3 and later: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-flatten

Comment: @chron thanks! you are right; observation error (facepalm). I was looking at the class methods. `Hash.flatten`, indeed, does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>427</s> 384 characters

```
alias x puts
p={}
loop{
print'> '
case(u=gets.chop.split)[0]when'exit'
x'The pie store has closed!'
exit
when'list'
p.each{|k,v|printf"| %-#{p.keys.map(&:size).max}s | %-#{p.map{|e,a|a.to_s.size}.max}s |\n",k,v}
when'count'
x p[t=u[1]]||"There is no #{t} pie!"
when/sell|buy/
m=(u[0]<?s?1:-1)*u[1].to_i
if p[t=u[2]]
x p[t]+=m
else
x p[t]=m
end
else x"That's not a valid command."
end}
```

Thanks to Jan Dvorak of huge improvement from 427 to 384 (!)

Comment: You can use `loop{...}` instead of `while 1do...end`.

Comment: You can use `split` without its argument. By default, it splits by whitespace (or `$;` if that is set)

Comment: `p.keys.group_by(&:size).max[0]` -- are you looking for `p.keys.map(&:size).max` or `p.map{|x,_|x.size}.max`? Here: `[(t=p.values).max.to_s.size,t.min.to_s.size].max` are you looking for `p.map{|_,x|x.to_s.size}.max`? I'm gonna take your idea and abuse the formatter, though :-)

Comment: `p[t]=p[t]+m` is equivalent to `p[t]+=m` (except `p[t]` is evaluated twice instead of once) and longer. Use the latter.

Comment: @JanDvorak Oooh, thanks for all the tips :D I thought Ruby didn't have a `+=` operator; that's why I didn't use it. Maybe that's just for `++`. I will edit my post shortly

Answer (score 3):

## <del>Python</del> *Pie*-thon 437

I'm sure there is some slack on the second last line, but the requirement to align the bars for both the pie type and number is a doozy.

```
p,C,l={},"count",len
while 1:
 a=raw_input("> ").split();c=a.pop(0)
 if"exit"==c:print"The pie store has closed!";break
 if"sell"==c:a[0]=int(a[0])*-1
 if c in[C,"buy","sell"]:
  y=a[-1]
  if c!=C:p[y]=p.get(y,0)+int(a[0])
  print p.get(y,"There is no %s pie!"%y)
 elif"list"==c:
  for i in p:print"| %s | %s |"%(i.ljust(l(max(p.keys(),l))),str(p[i]).rjust(max([l(str(x)) for x in p.values()])))
 else:print"That's not a valid command."
```

As per Igby Largeman's comment the rules are unclear around what to do if there **was** a pie of a specific type, but there are `0` now. So I've interpreted it in my favour.

Sample output:

```
> buy 10 apple
10
> sell 1 blueberry
-1
> buy 1 keylime
1
> sell 3 apple
7
> buy 5 blueberry
4
> list
| keylime   | 1 |
| apple     | 7 |
| blueberry | 4 |
> sell 1 keylime
0
> count keylime
0
```

Comment: Sorry, but in this one `> count potato` produces `That's not a valid command.` instead of `There is no potato pie!`

Comment: @Doorknob Are you running it in IDLE?

Comment: Yes. I'll try in a file

Comment: Actually, [count doesn't seem to be working at all](http://i.imgur.com/zHhjYiB.png). Actually it works sometimes but sometimes it doesn't. It's very odd...

Comment: Aha! `count` breaks after `list`ing. [image](http://i.imgur.com/xnqCnlc.png) (also your `count` is missing an exclamation point if it can't find the pie)

Comment: Very odd. Such is the trobule with code golf. I'll fix it up.

Comment: @Doorknob HAHAHAHA, its becuase I used `x` as shorthand for `"count"` and as a loop variable.

Comment: Hehe, I knew it was a naming clash of some kind :P +1 Oh and also, my file for your program had an amusing name: `pie.py` :P

Answer (score 3):

### C# - <strike>571 568</strike> 559

Bringing up the rear as usual with the hopelessly verbose C#.

```cs
using C=System.Console;class Z{static void Main(){var P=new 
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int>();int i=0,n;a:C.Write
("> ");var I=C.ReadLine().Split(' ');var c=I[0];object s=c=="exit"?
"The pie store has closed!":"That's not a valid command.";if(c==
"count")try{s=P[c=I[1]];}catch{s="There is no "+c+" pie!";}if(c==
"buy"||c=="sell"){n=int.Parse(I[1]);n=c=="sell"?-n:n;try{n+=P[c=
I[2]];}catch{}s=P[c]=n;i=(n=c.Length)>i?n:i;}if(c=="list")foreach(
var p in P.Keys)C.Write("| {0,"+-i+"} | {1,11} |\n",p,P[p]);else C.
WriteLine(s);if(c!="exit")goto a;}}
```

[image]

I took some liberty with the rule about list output. To save some characters I hardcoded the width of the count column to the maximum width of an integer value. (The rules didn't say extra spaces weren't allowed.)

Formatted:

```cs
using C = System.Console;
class Z
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var P = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>();
        int i = 0, n;
    a:
        C.Write("> ");
        var I = C.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        var c = I[0];
        object s = c == "exit" ? "The pie store has closed!" 
                               : "That's not a valid command.";

        // allow Dictionary to throw exceptions; cheaper than using ContainsKey()
        if (c == "count")
            try { s = P[c = I[1]]; }
            catch { s = "There is no " + c + " pie!"; }

        if (c == "buy" || c == "sell")
        {
            n = int.Parse(I[1]);
            n = c == "sell" ? -n : n;

            try { n += P[c = I[2]]; }
            catch { }

            s = P[c] = n;
            i = (n = c.Length) > i ? n : i;
        }

        if (c == "list")
            foreach (var p in P.Keys) 
                C.Write("| {0," + -i + "} | {1,11} |\n", p, P[p]);
        else
            C.WriteLine(s);

        if (c != "exit") goto a; // goto is cheaper than a loop
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, I'm surprised that you can get such a low character count with such a verbose language :D

Comment: My goal with the Java is only to beat the C# implementation.  Haha.  Nice job with this one.

Answer (score 1):

## Java - <s>772</s> <s>751</s> <s>739</s> <s>713</s> <s>666</s> 619

I know it's not winning the contest, but just for fun!

```
import java.util.*;class a{static<T>void p(T p){System.out.print(p);}public static
 void main(String[]s){z:for(Map<String,Long>m=new HashMap();;){p("> ");s=new
 Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");switch(s[0]){case"list":for(Map.Entry 
e:m.entrySet())System.out.printf("|%12s|%6s|\n",e.getKey(),e.getValue());break;
case"count":p(m.get(s[1])!=null?m.get(s[1]):"There is no "+s[1]+" pie!\n");break;
case"buy":case"sell":long r=(s[0].length()==3?1:-1)*new Long(s[1])+(m.get(s[2])!=null?
m.get(s[2]):0);p(r+"\n");m.put(s[2],r);break;case"exit":p("The pie store has
 closed!");break z;default:p("That's not a valid command.\n");}}}}
```

With line breaks and tabs:

```
import java.util.*;

class a{

    static<T>void p(T p){
        System.out.print(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[]s){
        z:for(Map<String,Long>m=new HashMap();;){
            p("\n> ");
            s=new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");
            switch(s[0]){
            case"list":
                for(Map.Entry e:m.entrySet())
                    System.out.printf("|%12s|%6s|\n",e.getKey(),e.getValue());
                break;
            case"count":
                p(m.get(s[1])!=null?m.get(s[1]):"There is no "+s[1]+" pie!");
                break;
            case"buy":
            case"sell":
                long r=(s[0].length()==3?1:-1)*new Long(s[1])+(m.get(s[2])!=null?m.get(s[2]):0);
                p(r);
                m.put(s[2],r);
                break;
            case"exit":
                p("The pie store has closed!");
                break z;
            default:
                p("That's not a valid command.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for a non-traditional golfing language :). With C# I found that the switch statement is more expensive than simple if{} constructs. This should be true for Java too.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman Yeah, I kept trying to get `if/else` to be less expensive, but due to the fact that I'd have to do `s[0]=s[0].intern()` in order to compare with `==`, it always ends up being *more*.  I know, very counterintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 310

```py
p={}
c=G=p.get
while c:
 l=("exit list buy count sell "+input("> ")).split();c=l.index(l[5]);*_,n=l
 if~-c%2*c:p[n]=(3-c)*int(l[6])+G(n,0)
 print(["The pie store has closed!","\n".join("| %*s | %9s |"%(max(map(len,p)),k,p[k])for k in p),G(n),G(n,"There is no %s pie!"%n),G(n),"That's not a valid command."][c])
```